# How to use jshint efficiently in a project consisting of interdependent javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I'm new to javascript (coming from C/C++/Java), so please bear with me.

It seems to me that linting is a good thing to do. However, I'm getting a lot of "undefined variable/reference" errors, and I don't see how to solve that problem in a 'good/efficient way'.

Let's say I have a larger project written in Html/Javascript. So I want to split it into js-modules that depend on each other, e.g.:

```
common_utils.js (depends on external lib d3.js)
app1.js (depends on common_utils.js)
app2.js (depends on common_utils.js as well)
```

First there is no way of including/referencing commmon_utils.js into/to app1.js, right? I can only use dynamic loading from the html file, right?

(I mean, isn't that kind of weird? Seems like the most normal thing to do...!! (again: I'm coming from C++/Java))

Ok, fair enough, so there is no way for jslint/hint to figure out that common_utils.js will only be used when d3.js is loaded. No problem, I add

global d3

to my jshint configuration, since everything is under that 'namespace'. Not pretty, but all right.

But what about my common_utils.js?
I don't want to manually add linter exceptions for every single function definition in that file.

Do I get something entirely wrong about how to organize and develop projects in javascript?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I get something entirely wrong about how to organize and develop projects in javascript?

No, you're on the money.

It sounds like `common_utils.js` is in your control, correct? That is, it's your code? I'm going to assume it is for now.

---

If you find that you're adding exceptions for every function, then you're not **[namespacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#JavaScript_Object_Oriented_Programming)**, which will make linting *lots* easier.

Note that this is what d3js is doing, give or take. Here's an example of d3 usage with the `d3` namespace from their website:

> D3 employs a declarative approach, operating on arbitrary sets of
>   nodes called selections. For example, you can rewrite the above loop
>   as:
>
> `d3.selectAll("p").style("color", "white");`

See that `d3` object? You need to do the same thing.

You should declare a single "parent" object in `common_utils.js` and attach every function to it. **Then you only need to declare one global in your JSL/Hint settings to get *all* of `common_util.js`'s functions.**

Here are two quick, non-OO examples. The first is probably the most straightforward.

> Note that you *do* need the  (space) between the `function` keyword and its first parens. That is, `var spam = function ()` is correct in JSLint and `var spam = function()` is not. JSLint thinks the second looks like a typical named function, not an assignment. Fair enough.

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true, sloppy: true, white: true */
var commonUtils = {};   // create the "parent" object.

// then add your functions to it, one by one.
commonUtils.test1 = function (myString) {
    if (console.log) { console.log("myString is: " + myString); }
};

commonUtils.test2 = function (myString) {
    window.alert("myString is: " + myString);
};
```

... or -- and this is a little more common, I think -- you can use JSON notation, which is easy enough to understand once you've got the above example down:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true, sloppy: true, white: true */
var commonUtils = {
    test1: function (myString)    {
        if (console.log) { console.log("myString is: " + myString); }
    },
    test2: function (myString)    {
        window.alert("myString is: " + myString);
    }
};
```

You can also [go full object oriented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_Objects), if that's important, but it doesn't sound like it's required for you now. Namespacing should do the trick.

Now you can invoke with code like this...

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true, sloppy: true, white: true */
/*global commonUtils */

commonUtils.test1("console write");
commonUtils.test2("alert write");
```

The only item in your globals list is `commonUtils`, no matter how many functions you have in its namespace. Voila.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense, does solve my problem and gives some useful background info. However, it seems like JSL/Hint doesn't recognize misspelled function calls anymore when they are 'hidden' by a defined variable/namespace. E.g. `d3.thereIsNoSuchFunction()` isn't reported as an error. That's a pity!

Comment: Ah, good call. JSLint is file-specific, and might consider checking function names outside of the scope of a linter, though it *would* be nice. [Steve Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/17/using-jshint-inside-visual-studio-the-basics/) (KnockoutJS's author) makes a related point on JSHint drawbacks: `"JavaScript is fully dynamic, so the linter can’t know whether or not a given object will have a certain property at runtime."` That's fair, though, as you say, a good warning would be nice. [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) might try to do this; can't recall.

Comment: WebStorm does report it as a 'weak warning' - that's something, and I guess all that's possible, since Steve Sanderson does make a good point there... Thanks again.